# Asp.net-identity ApplicationUser property on POCO loads as null

Tags: ef-code-first, poco, asp.net-identity

I have a model

```
public class BaseCave

    public string OldSasaCode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cave Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser LastEditMember { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}

public class Cave: BaseCave
{
    public int CaveID { get; set; }
}
```

and i use this on ApplicationDbContext created by ASP.NET-Identiy.
I set the LastEditMember property equals to the current logged in member and save.

In the DB the last editmember's ID is Saved in my Cave table, but when i load the Cave entity, the LastEditMember property is null, eventhough the ID for the user was sucsesfully saved in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any Related Entities must be marked as virtual for entity framework to be able to use them.

This also indicates to Entity Framework that it is a related Entity.

So in this example it should have been:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser LastEditMember { get; set; }
```